# How to match many combinations of function arguments in R?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, functional-programming, switch-statement

Can we create a 2-dimensional array for matching combinations of two function arguments?

For example, if I write a function with 1 argument (in addition to data input argument):

```r
choose_procedure <- function(x, what_to_do) {
  switch(what_to_do,
         "mean"   = {...}, # mean(x) or mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) or weighted.mean(x)
         "median" = {...}, # median(x)
         "square" = {...}, # x * x or x ^ 2
         "unique" = {...}, # unique(x)
         "log"    = {...}  # log(x) or log10(x)
  )
}
```

I added inline comments to imply that there could be more than one choice per `what_to_do` input.

When `what_to_do` = `"mean"`, should it be `mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)` or `mean(x, na.rm = FALSE)`?
Likewise, when `what_to_do` = `"log"`, should it be `log(x)` or `log10(x)`? Etc.

To handle this, I thought to introduce another argument to `choose_procedure()`, called `"scenario"`. So if the call to `choose_procedure()` is:

```r
choose_procedure(x = mtcars$mpg, what_to_do = "log", scenario = "A")
```

Then it would execute `log(mtcars$mpg)`.

But if the call is

```r
choose_procedure(x = mtcars$mpg, what_to_do = "log", scenario = "B")
```

then it would execute `log10(mtcars$mpg)`.

---

An example with just `"log"` and `"scenario"` describes a 2x2 array:

- `"what_to_do"` has 2 options: `log()` or `log10()`
- `"scenario"` has two options: `"A"` or `"B"`

Clearly, this could be handled with 4 if-statements (one for each combination), but will become very difficult to program if we have more combinations (as in `choose_procedure()` example I opened with).

So I have two questions:

1. I'm looking for a setup that could be extended to potentially any *n* × *n* array.
2. In fact, maybe there's a way to generalize to more than *n* × *n*? For example, if we have 3 arguments: `"what_do_to"`, `"scenario"`, `"sub_scenario"`. Etc.

Comment: Read about `match.fun`

Comment: You can, but it’s generally not a good idea. Your code seems to want to emulate OOP or functional programming with strings. Use the proper tools instead — i.e. higher-order functions, or OOP, or whatever. In particular, you seem to be reinventing the strategy pattern.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, what do you mean by `reinventing the strategy pattern`? I guess this question is indeed about functional programming (although I didn't realize that when posting). But isn't FP encouraged in R?

Comment: @Emman FP *is*, but your code isn’t FP — it uses [string typing](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) instead of using proper types, i.e. functions, where appropriate.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, so should I infer from your comment that wurli's answer below is improper because it uses strings?

Comment: @Emman wurli’s answer is a good solution when using strings. But, yes, a better solution would be not to use strings in the first place, as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those things where there are many ways to tackle the problem, and the best one is very likely to be dependant on the context you actually want to use it in. However, in the situation you outlined, here's how I would approach it:

```r
choose_procedure <- function(x, ...) {
  
  # Define a table of options
  choices <- tibble::tribble(
    ~what_to_do,  ~scenario,                ~result,
         "mean",        "A",                   mean,
         "mean",        "B", ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
         "mean",        "C",          weighted.mean,
       "median",        "A",                 median,
       "square",        "A",                 ~. * .,
       "square",        "B",                 ~. ^ 2,
       "unique",        "A",                 unique,
          "log",        "A",                    log,
          "log",        "B",                  log10
  )
  
  # Filter the table down to the desired option
  choice <- dplyr::filter(choices, ...)
  
  # Stop if no options available
  if (nrow(choice) == 0) {
    stop("No such option available")
  }
  
  # Warn if multiple options available, and use first
  if (nrow(choice) > 1) {
    choice <- head(choices, 1)
    warning("More than one option available, using first scenario")
  }
  
  # Transform any purrr-style lambda functions to normal functions
  fun <- rlang::as_function(choice$result[[1]])
  
  # Perform the calculation
  fun(x)
  
}

choose_procedure(x = mtcars$mpg, what_to_do == "log", scenario == "B")
#>  [1] 1.322219 1.322219 1.357935 1.330414 1.271842 1.257679 1.155336 1.387390
#>  [9] 1.357935 1.283301 1.250420 1.214844 1.238046 1.181844 1.017033 1.017033
#> [17] 1.167317 1.510545 1.482874 1.530200 1.332438 1.190332 1.181844 1.123852
#> [25] 1.283301 1.436163 1.414973 1.482874 1.198657 1.294466 1.176091 1.330414
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

```
choose_procedure <- function(x, FUN, ...){
   if(...length()) FUN(x, ...)
   else FUN(x)
 }

x <- c(1,3,5,NA, 10)

choose_procedure(x, mean)
[1] NA

choose_procedure(x, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 4.75

choose_procedure(x, log)
[1] 0.000000 1.098612 1.609438       NA 2.302585

choose_procedure(x, log10)
[1] 0.0000000 0.4771213 0.6989700        NA 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. However your solution handles the specific situation where the user knows to select the relevant function upfront. But I want the input argument be more high-level. For example `choose_procedure(x = my_df, FUN = "wrangle_data", data_source = c("my_mom", "my_brother"))`. So `"wrangle_data"` is just a label, not an actual function name. Much like in `switch()`. And `"wrangle_data"` calls, in turn, to a lower-level function (maybe `unique` or `na.omit` or whatever I decide, according to `data_source` arg)

Comment: @Emman, Since "wrangle_data" will call a lower function, consider naming the lower level function as wrangle_data. Then you could use the same procedure as above.

Comment: @Emman You could also invoke the `match.fun` . There is no need to have a `switch`. Unless of course the functions are in a list.

Comment: could you perhaps add some explanation about how your solution works? I mean, how would you explain `if(...length()) FUN(x, ...)` to a human? I've tried googling it but didn't find insight. Or is there a reference/textbook that discusses this kind of strategy? Thanks!

Comment: @Emman the if statement claims that if you pass any additional arguments, ie the `length(...)>0` then the function uses additional parameters hence run the function with the additional parameters. ie mean, median etc. Note that `log` only takes one parameter, `x` hence just need FUN(x) but mean can be `mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)`, thus `FUN(x, na.rm = TRUE)` hence `FUN(x, ...)` where the ellipsis stands for additional arguments

Comment: Thanks. I'm especially intrigued by the `...length()` condition. From your comment I gather that it's equivalent to `length(...) > 0`, but when I rewrite the function to: `choose_procedure_2 <- function(x, FUN, ...){ if(length(...) > 0) FUN(x, ...) else FUN(x) }` then I get errors.

Comment: @Emman that is because you need to use the `list` ie `length(list(...)) > 0`. Ellipsis have a different way of being dealt with