# How to store both function and its input data inside designated tibble columns, then iterate over rows to execute?

Tags: r, functional-programming, mapping, purrr, tibble

I'm trying to run a data wrangling procedure inside a *tibble* using tools from `{purrr}` package. My method is to organize everything I need inside a tibble:

- the input data inside a column
- the *function* to apply upon the input data gets its own column too

My problem: how can I use purrr's mapping functions to say "*take the function stored in column `x` and apply it over the data in column `y`*"?

Below is a minimal example, based on `mtcars` and `iris`. I want to summarise each data set, in the same workflow: first subset columns, then do some aggregation. For the aggregation part, I preemptively set up 2 functions, one for each data.

- `summarise_iris()`
- `summarise_mtcars()`

Then I organize all I need inside a tibble (see `trb` object below).

The first part, the subsetting, works well. As can be seen in `trb_1` below, `dat_selected` is a new column I mutated, which stores the output of the subset step.

However, the second part is not working. I want to take the function in column `summarise_func` and apply it over the data stored in column `dat_selected`. But it's not working. Why not? I purposely used `map()` because it maps only 1 input to the function.

```r
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

summarise_iris <- function(.dat) {
  .dat %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
}
# to test: iris %>% summarise_iris()

summarise_mtcars <- function(.dat) {
  .dat %>%
    group_by(am) %>%
    summarise(mpg_median = median(mpg))
}
# to test: mtcars %>% summarise_mtcars()

trb <- 
  tribble(~original_data, ~cols_to_select,                               ~summarise_func,
          mtcars,         c("am", "disp", "mpg"),                        ~summarise_mtcars(.),
          iris,           c("Species", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"),   ~summarise_iris(.)
  )

trb_1 <- 
  trb %>%
  mutate(dat_selected   = map2(.x = original_data, .y = cols_to_select, .f = ~select(.x, all_of(.y)))) 

trb_1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   original_data  cols_to_select summarise_func dat_selected  
#>   <list>         <list>         <list>         <list>        
#> 1 <df [32 x 11]> <chr [3]>      <formula>      <df [32 x 3]> 
#> 2 <df [150 x 5]> <chr [3]>      <formula>      <df [150 x 3]>

trb_1 %>%
  mutate(dat_summarised = map(.x = dat_selected, .f = summarise_func))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `dat_summarised`.
#> i `dat_summarised = map(.x = dat_selected, .f = summarise_func)`.
#> x Index 1 must have length 1, not 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

---

How can I achieve the desired output (see below) using the in-table method I'm trying to incorporate? I.e.:

```r
trb_1 %>%
  mutate(dat_summarised = map(.x = dat_selected, .f = summarise_func))

## to give the desired output that's equivalent to what we get if we run:
summar_mtcars <- mtcars %>% summarise_mtcars()
summar_iris   <- iris %>% summarise_iris()

trb_1 %>%
  tibble::add_column(dat_summarised = list(summar_mtcars, summar_iris))

## # A tibble: 2 x 5
##   original_data  cols_to_select summarise_func dat_selected   dat_summarised  
##   <list>         <list>         <list>         <list>         <list>          
## 1 <df [32 x 11]> <chr [3]>      <formula>      <df [32 x 3]>  <tibble [2 x 2]>
## 2 <df [150 x 5]> <chr [3]>      <formula>      <df [150 x 3]> <tibble [3 x 3]>
```

---

UPDATE

---

I don't know if the following is in the right direction, but based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69709688/6105259), I thought to utilize `rlang::as_function()` such that:

```r
trb_1 %>%
  mutate(dat_summarised = map(.x = dat_selected, .f = ~rlang::as_function(summarise_func)))
```

But it gives a different error now:

> x Can't convert a list to function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take a simpler approach. First, we don't need to select columns, that's inherent to `summarize` anyway. Let's create columns that define the columns to group by, the columns to summarize, and functions to use.

```r
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)


trb <- 
  tribble(~original_data, ~cols_to_group, ~cols_to_summarize,    ~summarise_func,
          mtcars,         "am",           "mpg",                 \(x) mean(x, na.rm = T),
          iris,           "Species",      ~starts_with("Sepal"), median
  )
```

<sup>The `\(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)` syntax is the new [anonymous function syntax](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-new-pipe-and-anonymous-function-syntax-in-r-54d98861014c) in R 4.1. If using an earlier version, just change to `function(x) mean(...)`</sup>

Now we can define a function (to eventually use in `pmap` that accepts the data, grouping columns, columns to analyse, and the summarize functions.

```r
summarize_fun <- function(
  .dat, .group_cols, .summ_cols, .funs
) {
  .dat %>%
    group_by(across(!!.group_cols)) %>%
    summarize(across(!!.summ_cols, .funs))

}
```

And now we can just use these within `mutate(pmap(...))` to get the result we want. I rely on `!!` for unquoting expressions because that works for passing in things like `~starts_with("Sepal")`, which don't work with `{{ }}` to my knowledge.

```r
trb_final <- trb %>%
  mutate(dat_summarized = pmap(
    list(
      .dat=original_data,
      .group_cols=cols_to_group,
      .summ_cols=cols_to_summarize,
      .funs=summarise_func
    ),
    summarize_fun
  ))

trb_final
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   original_data  cols_to_group cols_to_summarize summarise_func dat_summarized  
#>   <list>         <chr>         <list>            <list>         <list>          
#> 1 <df [32 × 11]> am            <chr [1]>         <fn>           <tibble [2 × 2]>
#> 2 <df [150 × 5]> Species       <formula>         <fn>           <tibble [3 × 3]>

trb_final$dat_summarized
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0  17.1
#> 2     1  24.4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
#>   <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 setosa              5           3.4
#> 2 versicolor          5.9         2.8
#> 3 virginica           6.5         3
```

---

### General functions

If instead as in the comments, we want just to apply generic functions to summarize, then just rely on `pmap` with 2 arguments, the data and the summarizing function.

```r
summarize_mtcars <- function(.dat) {
  .dat %>%
    group_by(am) %>%
    summarise(mpg_median = median(mpg))
}

summarize_iris <- function(.dat) {
  .dat %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
}
```

Now we can just define our data frame to analyze using the original data and the two `summarize_...` functions we defined for the datasets.

```r
trb <- 
  tribble(~original_data, ~summarize_func,
          mtcars,         summarize_mtcars,
          iris,           summarize_iris
  )
```

And then just use `pmap` as before (can also use `map2` of course).

```r
trb_final <- trb %>%
  mutate(dat_summarized = pmap(
    list(
      original_data,
      summarize_func
    ),
    \(.d, .f) .f(.d)
  ))

trb_final
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   original_data  summarize_func dat_summarized  
#>   <list>         <list>         <list>          
#> 1 <df [32 × 11]> <fn>           <tibble [2 × 2]>
#> 2 <df [150 × 5]> <fn>           <tibble [3 × 3]>

trb_final$dat_summarized
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am mpg_median
#>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     0       17.3
#> 2     1       22.8
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
#>   <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 setosa             5.01        3.43
#> 2 versicolor         5.94        2.77
#> 3 virginica          6.59        2.97
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a really nice solution. The main limitation is that it overfits to the specific example I gave. I chose a simple example to convey the point in the clearest way. However, in my real data, the wrangling procedures (in each row of `trb`) are _very_ different from each other, and cannot be united into a single summarizing function.

Comment: @Emman Then just amend the wrapper function accept custom summarize function. I've quickly done it. `pmap` is still the solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. One question still: the wrapper `my_summarize()` is so minimal, that I wonder why we shouldn't use an anonymous function inside `pmap`'s `.f` argument, instead of creating a standalone function. Such as `.f = function(.dat, .func) .func(.dat)` or more concisely `.f = \(.dat, .func) .func(.dat)`. Or is it just a matter of coding style?

Comment: Ah, you definitely could, just had a standalone already so modified it ha!

Answer (score 1):

I would store the functions as strings:

```r
trb <- 
  tribble(~original_data, ~cols_to_select,                               ~summarise_func,
          mtcars,         c("am", "disp", "mpg"),                        "summarise_mtcars",
          iris,           c("Species", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"),   "summarise_iris"
  )
```

Then you can simply use `do.call` in your `map` call. Or you convert your functions to strings on the fly with `mutate`:

```r
trb_2 <- trb_1 %>%
  mutate(summarise_func = as.character(summarise_func)) %>% 
  mutate(dat_summarised = map2(summarise_func, original_data, ~ do.call(what = .x, args = list(.dat = .y))))

trb_2
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   original_data  cols_to_select summarise_func   dat_selected   dat_summarised  
#>   <list>         <list>         <chr>            <list>         <list>          
#> 1 <df [32 × 11]> <chr [3]>      summarise_mtcars <df [32 × 3]>  <tibble [2 × 2]>
#> 2 <df [150 × 5]> <chr [3]>      summarise_iris   <df [150 × 3]> <tibble [3 × 3]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Update: Storing functions or rather function names as strings can be problematic if the underlying function changes (I get that now). The problem is getting the function into the tibble in the first place. What you do in the question is storing it as a formula. A better way is (imo) to store it in a list column:

```r
trb <- 
  tribble(~original_data, ~cols_to_select,                               ~summarise_func,
          mtcars,         c("am", "disp", "mpg"),                        list(fun = summarise_mtcars),
          iris,           c("Species", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"),   list(fun = summarise_iris)
  )
```

With a slight adaptation, this original answer then works like this:

```r
trb_3 <- trb_1 %>%
  mutate(dat_summarised = map2(summarise_func, original_data, ~ do.call(what = .x$fun, args = list(.dat = .y))))


trb_3
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   original_data  cols_to_select summarise_func   dat_selected   dat_summarised  
#>   <list>         <list>         <list>           <list>         <list>          
#> 1 <df [32 × 11]> <chr [3]>      <named list [1]> <df [32 × 3]>  <tibble [2 × 2]>
#> 2 <df [150 × 5]> <chr [3]>      <named list [1]> <df [150 × 3]> <tibble [3 × 3]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69709319/how-to-match-many-combinations-of-function-arguments-in-r/69709688#comment123218043_69709319) advised to shy away from using strings as proxies to functions. I wonder if it's possible in the current scenario.